# php/mysql registration with email verification

Tags: php, mysql

What have i done wrong here? I have include two pages the first is the save.php and the second is the thank you which must echo after the user has successfully registered.

save.php

```
if($mail->Send()) {

            }
            unset($_SESSION['GENRE_REQUEST']);

    }
    header('Location:index.php?page=thanku=1');
    exit();
}
else
{
    header('Location:index.php?page=thanku=1');
    exit();
}
```

---

thanku.php

```
  <?php if(!empty($_GET['msg']))
                              { 

  if($_GET['msg']==1) 
                              { ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><b>Thank You for Registering With us.</b> <br />
      <br />please activate your profile by clicking on the activation link sent to your email address.<br/></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What are your errors? What are you expecting?

Comment: if i understood correctly, it seems your syntax is wrong, you are not re-directing into tnahku.php and use this `Location:thanku.php?msg=1` instead of `Location:index.php?page=thanku=1`

Answer (score 3):

You never send the variable `$_GET['msg']`. You are redirecting like this

```
header('Location:index.php?page=thanku=1');
```

change it to this and you will see your message

```
header('Location:index.php?page=thanku&msg=1');
```

Comment: i have changed it to this and still don't get the message

Comment: i have changed it to this but still dont get the message '}
        header('Location:index.php?page=thanku&msg=1');
        exit();
       }
       else
       {
        header('Location:index.php?page=thanku&msg=1');
        exit(); '
       }

Comment: 1. is thanku included into index.php at the correct moment. - 2. Have you replaced all occurences? - 3. If you think you have replaced all occurences, check by checking the url you are redirected to. - If all this doesn't help I can not help you any further with the information given right now.

Comment: ok i have tried for testing purpose the following: '}
          unset($_SESSION['GENRE_REQUEST']);
          
        }
        header('Location:thanku.php');
        exit();
       }
       else
       {
        header('Location:thanku.php');
        exit(); '
       }

Answer (score 2):

that is wrong

```
header('Location:index.php?page=thanku=1');
```

you forget msg

```
header('Location:index.php?page=thanku&msg=1');
```